# How to get correct width and height after rotation of Textblock in UWP

Tags: uwp, rotation, textblock, rendertransform, layouttransform

I need to get auto size of TextBlock after rotation. Below is the code I am using to rotate the TextBlock by 90 degree with the help of RenderTransform, But It takes up more space than it needed after rotating.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
     <TextBlock Text="Testing" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
         <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
              <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
         </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
     </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

In WPF, with the help of LayoutTransform, I can able to get the auto size (height and width) of the textblock properly. But in UWP, LayoutTranform is not available.

How can I get correct height and width of Textblock after rotation in UWP?

Regards,
Shobika.

Comment: You said auto size, do you mean actual size?

Answer (score 0):

You could get height and width value of `TextBlock` with [`ActualHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight) and [`ActualWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth) property. you could also subscribe [`SizeChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.sizechanged) event when the size changed, you could get the new size from `SizeChangedEventArgs`. But the actual height and width does not **exchange** after rotation 90°, so the `SizeChanged` will not be invoked.